# Change of itinerary on a Russian visa

Tags: visas, russia, kaliningrad

I have a (single-entry) Russian tourist visa for an upcoming trip. I initially applied the visa for a visit to Moscow but I'm now considering to go to Kaliningrad as well (on a direct flight from Moscow). Is this possible or would I be facing any problems changing the itinerary I provided during my application?

I am on an Austrian passport.

Comment: Single-entry tourist visa, Austrian passport. I'll update the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Cheers from Kaliningrad. There should be no problems with that as long as you take a flight.

Train, Bus or Car trip is a completely different story, though.

Comment: Please elaborate..

Comment: @JJJ Kaliningrad is an exclave so, if you go to Moscow and then travel there by land, you'll have to leave Russia, cross some combination of Latvia, Lithuania, Belarus and Poland, and re-enter. But the asker has a single-entry visa so won't be able to re-enter.

Comment: There was a special visa-free program to enter Kaliningrad but it ended in 2017. Now you have to have a regular Russian visa. Because the OP has a single entry visa he must fly directly to Kaliningrad from elsewhere in Russia, or fly in the reverse direction.

Answer (score 2):

I completely changed my itinerary, and I had no problem (Swiss passport here). Nobody ask me the reason of the change.

Just keep the new itinerary dates within the expected dates, and do not change the purpose.